# Cake php Text Helper Issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Cake php Text Helper Issue

In view.ctp

```
$userName = 'Jusnitdustinwq'; 
echo $this->Text->truncate( $userName, 8, array('ending' => '...', 'exact' => false));
```

In document of cake php [truncate](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1469/Text#truncate-1625) it is written as  if 'exact' is 'false', then `$userName` will not be cut mid-word, but here no word or `$username` is displaying, instead only `...` is displaying here for above example

How to correct it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $this->Text->truncate($userName , 8, array('ending' => '...'));
```

**Or**

```
echo $this->Text->truncate($userName , 8, array('ending' => '...', 'exact' => true));
```

problem cause by `exact` param, because `$userName` is not a collection of words separated by space and `exact => true` works on that type of input.

If you try like following, will see the fact:

```
$userName = 'Ju snit dustinwq'; 

echo $this->Text->truncate($userName , 8, array('ending' => '...', 'exact' =>  false));
```

Comment: It's a name, I dont want to cut it off in mid-word, if `$username`  is single word. But if `$username` collection of words is there, then I need to cut off with its first word. I already tried with `'exact' => true`.

Comment: @Jusnit then you have to check that `$userName` is a single word or collection of words

Answer (score 1):

It's working as intended.  In your example, if you set `'exact'=>false`, it tries to find a space somewhere **at/before 8 characters** to truncate there, but **there are none**.  So, the only way it can keep your string below 8 characters and not cut off a word, is by removing all the text and just using "...".

**Instead, try this:**

```
$userName = 'Jusnitdustinwq';
if(strpos($userName, ' ')) {
    echo $this->Text->truncate( $userName, 8, array('exact' => false));
} else {
    echo $this->Text->truncate( $userName, 8);
}
```

Notice, you don't need to specify `'ending'` unless you want to change it to something OTHER than the default, which is `'...'`;  The same goes withk `'exact'`, which has the default of `true`.